# Accessing localStorage data with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm using [form-persistence.min.js](https://github.com/FThompson/FormPersistence.js) to preserve form data on page refresh, It created this localStorage object.

```
{"prodName":["Testing Porject"],"priority":["Normal"],"targetDueDate":["02/26/2020"],"prodType":["IT Releases"],"description":["Register a form for persistence."]}
```

I'm having trouble accessing the prodName value, here's what I've tried.

```
$temp = localStorage.getItem("form#add-form");
console.log($temp); 
console.log($temp['prodName']); // undefined
console.log($temp.prodName[0]); // TypeError: $temp.prodName is undefined
console.log($temp.prodName); // undefined
```

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: localStorage stores strings. What you have there is JSON. Parse the value, then you can access the properties (`JSON.parse`).

Comment: That did it, thank you!!!